How do liberal Protestants translate the word ‘ἀρσενοκοίτης’ in 1 Corinthians 6:9 and 1 Timothy 1:10?
For the purpose of this question, assume a liberal Protestant perspective which does not consider homosexuality to be inherently sinful.
1 Corinthians 6:9:

Ἢ (Or) οὐκ (not) οἴδατε (do you know) ὅτι (that) ἄδικοι (the unrighteous) θεοῦ (of God) βασιλείαν (kingdom) οὐ (not) κληρονομήσουσιν (will inherit)? Μὴ (Do not) πλανᾶσθε (be deceived): οὔτε (neither) πόρνοι (the sexually immoral) οὔτε (nor) εἰδωλολάτραι (idolaters) οὔτε (nor) μοιχοὶ (adulterers) οὔτε (nor) μαλακοὶ (effeminate/passive partners in sexual immorality) οὔτε (nor) ἀρσενοκοῖται (???).


Or do you not know that wrongdoers will not inherit the kingdom of God? Do not be deceived: Neither the sexually immoral nor idolaters nor adulterers nor men who have sex with men. (NIV)

1 Timothy 1:10:

πόρνοις (for the sexually immoral), ἀρσενοκοίταις (???), ἀνδραποδισταῖς (for slave traders), ψεύσταις (for liars), ἐπιόρκοις (for perjurers), καὶ (and) εἴ (if) τι (anything) ἕτερον (else) τῇ (to the) ὑγιαινούσῃ (sound) διδασκαλίᾳ (teaching) ἀντίκειται (is opposed).


For the sexually immoral, for those practicing homosexuality, for slave traders and liars and perjurers—and for whatever else is contrary to the sound doctrine. (NIV)


"ἀρσενοκοίτης" can literally be translated as "male-bedders", i.e. people practicing male homosexuality.  However, it would be the etymological fallacy to assume this meaning based on no other evidence.
My question is:
For liberal Protestants who do not consider the practice of homosexuality to be a sin according to God, how is the word "ἀρσενοκοίτης" understood and/or translated into English?
Please provide a reference to either the teachings of a mainstream church or a widely accepted apologist.

I will accept answers from:

The perspective of people who do not view Paul as being the word of God and/or who disregard Paul's writing for any other reason.
The perspsective of people who accept Paul as being the divinely inspired word of God but who do not interpret these passages as saying that homosexuality is always a sin.

I will not accept answers from the perspsective of people who believe homosexuality is inherently sinful -- that is not the purpose of this question.
I am specifically not asking whether, for example, gay sex outside of marriage is a sin, or whether adultery is a sin -- that is out of scope for this question.
I will accept answers along the lines of "ἀρσενοκοίτης means homosexuality but in the specific context of ...".

The root word κεῖμαι Biblehub-Strong-Thayer means 'to lie'. (The word 'bed' is not there.) I do not see how the etymological fallacy would be relevant in such a case. That only becomes a factor when usage departs from etymology. Which you would have to prove, historically, yourself. Rather than, as above, supposing to argue that etymology never defines a word's meaning. Or that 'other evidence' is, necessarily, required to lexically attach meaning to a particular lexeme by examining the word itself. Particularly where scripture is involved.

@NigelJ I accept that "ἀρσενοκοῖται" could be translated as "men who lie with men" or something like that (rather than "bed").  However, it would still be the etymological fallacy to assume, without other evidence, that this word means "homosexual" in general, because the point of the etymological fallacy is that words are not always the sum of their component parts.  However my point is not to prove this either way.  Rather, I would like to understand how a particular group (liberal Protestants) interprets this word.

You are ignoring the fact that we are dealing with holy scripture, the word of God. Even the very languages, Hebrew and Greek, evidence that Divine Providence shaped those languages for millenia before they were used to express Divine thoughts and purposes. Great confidence can be placed upon these words and their very structures. Those who depart from such confidence simply invent their own doctrine and 'wrest' the scripture as the apostle tells us.

@NigelJ I am not ignoring that.  I am not taking any position on this at all (except that, as a matter of fact, not all Christians interpret Paul's writing as the word of God).  My question is what a particular group of people understands about this word.  If you believe that liberal protestants "invent their own doctrine", that is an entirely reasonable position to hold, but it is orthogonal to what I am asking here.

"who are openly accepting of gay people."
I think you should rephrase that to: "who consider it acceptable to continue having sexual relations with members of the same sex." I'm not aware of any denom. that doesn't "accept gay people" with arms wide open.

@Displayname I have removed that paragraph from the question as I think it was redundant anyway.

I guess you just need to wait for someone from one of those churches that accept homosexuality, to explain it. Though I have a feeling that they have not done exegesis on the bible verses. I've heard strange things like voting on what sin is...

@Wyrsa As long as the question is not closed, I am happy to wait as long as necessary for an answer :-). I understand your point though, it's possible the group I'm addressing with this question does not study the bible in detail.
